# Is it possible to seamlessly combine MongoDB and GridFS when documents exceed 16MB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, gridfs

I'm currently databasing sensor data from an embedded project (see below for a crude schema).  I've been using MongoDB (via python3/pymongo) thus far without issue but recently, as a result of longer data logs, have files which exceeded the 16MB document limit.

```
{
  metadata: {
    startTime: Date,
    user: String,
    calibationParams: {
      K1: Number,
      K2: Number,
      ...
    }
  }
  data: {
    timestamps: Number[],
    sensorA: Number[],
    sensorB: Number[],
  ...
  }
}
```

I'm able to implement GridFS to store the larger documents but can't see any way to query them seamlessly alongside standard Mongo document data. The only approach I can see currently is to ensure that detailed metadata is kept for each GridFS file such that for all queries one can ascertain whether or not the whole file needs reading and parsing.

Does an API or library exist that encapsulates GridFS alongside Mongo to allow the normal set of Mongo instructions to be used? If not, what are my options? Is it better to split my time series data across documents to reduce size or should I be looking at a different database solution?

Thanks in advance,

P

Comment: No, there is no solution what you are searching... You need to change your collection structure, so single document could not expand (during time) to that 16MB.  One document should be one measure of one sensor or if sensor is sending information f.ex. every second, then one document have data of one sensor minute (60 measures)..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've now posted an answer with a link to an SO question that provides exactly the solution you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with my same problem, this answer covers the solution well:

[MongoDB workaround for document above 16mb size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175338/mongodb-workaround-for-document-above-16mb-size)