# What's the best way to store data in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, data-structures

I am wondering what's the best alternative for my data structure in MongoDB.

I have this collection :

Event collection

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "611ffe86c7db41a72d3b8635"
},
"title": "...",
"description": "...",
"creatorID": "...",
"imageUrl": "..."
}
```

And,

Comment collection :

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "some ID"
},
"eventID": "611ffe86c7db41a72d3b8635",
"text": "..."
}
```

In each event, there can be several publications. I did create two collections so from an Event ID I can call `Thing.find({ eventID: 'a event ID' })` and get all the publications from one event.

It's working fine but I saw that in one field it is possible to store arrays or multiple child for one parent. I was wondering if it would be best to use one of theses two structrues instead (only one collection) :

Sturcture 1 :

```
  {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "611ffe86c7db41a72d3b8635"
},
"title": "...",
"publications" : [ "PUBLICATION 1" , "PUBLICATION 2", ...  ]
"description": "...",
"creatorID": "...",
"imageUrl": "...",
}
```

Structure 2 :

```
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "611ffe86c7db41a72d3b8635"
    },
    "title": "...",
    "publications" : {
"1" : "Publication 1",
"2" : "Publication 2", 
"3" : "Publication 3", 
...
}
    "description": "...",
    "creatorID": "...",
    "imageUrl": "...",
    }
```

Taking into account that there could be millions of events and tens of millions of publications, what would be the best alternative according to thoses criterias :

-Query speed

-Cost

-Dynamic (Add one publication, modifiy it, delete it, ... )

-Maybe others?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Dynamic field names (e.g. `1`, `2`, `3`) is usually a bad design. So, use an array. In case you have really tens of millions of publications be aware, the max document size is 16 MiByte. In this case it would not work and you have to go for a completely different approach.

Comment: And why is my original solution combining two collections not good? 
For the publications limlits, is this approach a good way to go ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40178043/11097514

Comment: Actually my first solution might be a good alternative since dividing the data into two collections reduce the chance that a document exceed the 16 MB limit, right?

Answer (score 0):

you should use an `array` for this. Just like you said that it could be a really  huge data, `dynamically allocating memory` in that case cold make your program work `slower`.

Comment: But why would my first approach combining two collections be wrong ?